# How to convert Word document to PDF with copy protection

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, copy-protection

I need to convert a Word document to PDF file so that user would not be able to copy any text or anything from it (pdf file).

How can I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the not-copy flag in the pdf file using for example `pdftk` (there exists GUIs for it). You need to set an owner password.

But since many pdf readers ignore not-copy/not-print-flags, another option would be to convert all the text to vector paths using e.g. `inkscape`, but this would bloat the pdf file heavily.

In all cases, the user could use OCR-software to extract the text, so there is no safe solution.

Comment: pdftk original.pdf output result.pdf owner_pw asdf allow Printing

Comment: I have solved my problem using above pdftk command line. Thank you very much @jofel.

Comment: inkscape option was best one though, but my word document contained more than 100 pages and I had no time to import all of pages one-by-one into inkscape and to convert it to pdf.

Comment: @sunk818 Please read my full answer - the last sentence includes this case.

Answer (score -1):

Any PDF file can contain DRM (digital right management) feature: in other words a feature that disable copy-paste. You can find tons of software that does that, there are also few websites that propose to do it online without downloading a software (i.e online-pdf-nocopy.com)

Comment: The link you wrote is broken.